# Means of neighboring squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, means, rectangles

mn squares of equal size are arranged to form a rectangle of dimension m by n where m and n are natural numbers. Two squares will be called 'neighbours' if they have exactly one common side. A natural number is written in each square such that the number in written any square is the arithmetic mean of the numbers written in its neighbouring squares. Show that this is possible only if all the numbers used are equal.

We can assume this

```
      B
   C  A  D
      E
```

Therefore $A= (B+C+D+E)/4$

$4A = B+C+D+E$

What does mean ? Please solve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the minimal number $A$ in the rectangle.

Thus, by the given any neighbour numbers are equal to $A$.

Can you end it now?

About your new question. We can not solve this equation.

For example, $$4\cdot5=1+2+3+14=2+4+5+9=...$$

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by this. Is this a continuation of what I've done until now ?

Comment: @Shaurya Goyal It's a solution of your problem. I am ready to explain. Ask your question. Words, that you posted in the open post it's not solution. Why if $4A=B+C+D$ so $A=B=C=D?$

Comment: I edited the question. please explain it !

Comment: @Shaurya Goyal No, we can not solve this equation.

Comment: what would be the method to solve the sum from the beginning then?

Comment: @Shaurya Goyal You can not solve the starting problem by solving these equations in the general. Why you don't want to see the hint, which I posted? It solves your problem.

Comment: I did not understand the hint.  Take A to be the least value as in take A to be 1 ?

Comment: If $A=\min\{A,B,C,D,E\}$, so $4A=B+C+D+E\geq4A,$ which says $A=B=C=D=E.$

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal this technique is called the extremal principle. [This](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Extreme_principle#:~:text=The%20extreme%20principle%20(or%20extremal,positive%20integer%20in%20each%20square. ) AoPS link talks about it and interestingly uses the same example.