# Solution of single linear equation with 6 variables with the domain as the set of natural numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, solution-verification

How do I prove that all solutions to this equation:

> 22A = 6B + 6C + 7D + E + 2F

must satisfy these criteria:

> A = B = C = D = E = F

```
Note: It is given that all variables A, B, C, D, E and F are natural numbers.
```

[See the original problem here](https://www.sarthaks.com/263519/mn-squares-equal-size-are-arranged-form-rectangle-dimension-where-and-are-natural-numbers)

**EDIT:**

It was observed that the solution to the original problem was wrong in the given [link](https://www.sarthaks.com/263519/mn-squares-equal-size-are-arranged-form-rectangle-dimension-where-and-are-natural-numbers).

[Here is the correct solution of original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768600/means-of-neighboring-squares)

Comment: They need not.  $\{2,1,1,1,21,2\}$ looks like a valid solution.

Comment: @AndrewChin LeftHandSide = 44 but RightHandSide = 46

Comment: My mistake.  Regardless, my point still stands.

Comment: @JayramKumar Looking at the link, it seems that the "criteria" should be $B=C=D=E=F$.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, from that we can conclude that: "22A = 22B" and hence "A = B".

Comment: It's weird. If we have a solution set $\{a, b, c, d, e, f\}$, then also $\{a, b+1, c-1, d, e, f\}$ should be a solution, right? and $\{a-1, b, c, d, e+6, f\}$ , etc ...

Comment: Yes, the answer in the link is not a valid proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criteria need not be satisfied. If you write the equation like
$$
22A = 6(B+C) + 7D + E + 2F,
$$

you can see that if you take a solution for which $A=B=C=D=E=F$, you'll get solutions that do not satisfy the criteria simply keeping $B+C$ constant. For instance, if you find a solution with $B=C=4$, you have another solution with $B=5$, $C=3$.